# В предложениях нужно отыскать речевые ошибки и указать, какая именно нарушена норма

Tags: грамотная-речь, точное-словоупотребление

1. «Антошка соскучился прятаться под сестрой, ему хотелось посмотреть, что делается наружи, хотелось намокнуть на дожде».
2. «Он опробовал еще место, где лежала голова Юшки лицом вниз, и почувствовал, что земля там была сырая, ее залила кровь, хлынувшая горлом из Юшки».

*Знатоки, прошу помощи!*

Comment: тут не решают домашние задания, приведите свои попытки решения.

Answer (score 2):

Андрей Платонович Климентов. Русский советский писатель первой половины XX века. Прозаик, поэт, публицист, драматург, киносценарист, журналист, военный корреспондент. Один из наиболее самобытных писателей советской литературы с новаторским, ярким языком. Псевдонимы: Платонов, А. Фирсов, Ф. Человеков, А. Вагулов.

https://ilibrary.ru/text/1192/p.1/index.html
"Он опробовал еще место, где лежала голова Юшки лицом вниз, и почувствовал, что земля там была сырая, ее залила кровь, хлынувшая горлом из Юшки. — Помер, — вздохнул столяр. — Прощай, Юшка, и нас всех прости".

https://ilibrary.ru/text/2375/p.1/index.html
"Антошка соскучился прятаться под сестрой, ему хотелось посмотреть, что делается наружи, хотелось намокнуть на дожде, и он сказал Наташе: — Пусти..."

Если Вы прочтете оригинал, то поймете почему написано "прятаться под сестрой", а не "за сестрой".

Бросается в глаза, что сегодня (спустя много лет после написания этих строк) нам привычнее употреблять слово "снаружи", чем "наружи", а сочетанию "на дожде" мы предпочтем - "под дождем".

Не стоит искать ошибки в этих фразах. Их там нет...